# SQL injection concerns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-injection

ok i use this route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Catalog/Data",
            "Catalog/{*data}",
            new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", data = "" }
            );
```

the Url looks something like http://localhost/Catalog/Computer/Harddrives/internal

Data beening the Computer/Harddrives/internal part

i split it apart and validate the route
here is where my concerns are, atm i do not check for sql injection

i check the route by getting the category from the database using enitity framework
with this function

```
public Category GetByRoute(string Route)
    {
        return (from c in XEntity.CategorySet
                    .Where(c => c.Route == Route)
                    .Where(c => c.IsEnabled == true)
                select c).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

should i be worried about sql injection with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linq2Sql and the Entity Framework use SQL parameters (except for one edge case) so you'll be fine.

In your case you're actually using Linq over the CategorySet, and linq is executed locally in this case, so it's CategorySet that's touching the database, the where constraints run after (I believe). Again in this case there's no problem.

Comment: Linq2Sql has ExecuteQuery. This executes a raw query, so if you're naively building a query by string concatenation then you can pass in an injected string

Comment: You can't expect to get away with dangling that carrot, what's the one edge case?